# Group by a set of data and order items in each part separately from other parts in T SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a set of data that has 2 fields **ActivationTime** which is a type of `DATETIME` and **Score** which is a type of `INT`.

I want to group all of the data according to these rules:

- The minimum and maximum activation time values in each group ***must differ by no more than five days*** starting from the latest activation time. (In the sample below, the first activation time will be `2017-11-24 09:45:00.000`)
- Grouped data items must be ***sorted by the score value*** separately from other grouped data items

Consider the following data as an example:

```
Score                  ActivationTime
-------------------------------------------
  9               '2017-11-20 09:37:00.000'
  5               '2017-11-21 09:39:00.000'
  4               '2017-11-22 09:40:00.000'
  3               '2017-11-23 09:43:00.000'
  1               '2017-11-24 09:45:00.000'
  12              '2017-11-20 09:49:00.000'
  7               '2017-11-17 09:38:00.000'
  2               '2017-11-15 09:41:00.000'
  0               '2017-11-14 09:44:00.000'
  15              '2017-11-13 09:47:00.000'
  7               '2017-11-12 09:46:00.000'
  20              '2017-11-11 09:42:00.000'
  3               '2017-11-10 09:28:00.000'
  4               '2017-11-09 09:37:57.570'
```

Then I expect to get the following result:

```
Score                 ActivationTime             Category
---------------------------------------------------------------
  12             '2017-11-20 09:49:00.000'          1
  9              '2017-11-20 09:37:00.000'          1
  5              '2017-11-21 09:39:00.000'          1
  4              '2017-11-22 09:40:00.000'          1
  3              '2017-11-23 09:43:00.000'          1
  1              '2017-11-24 09:45:00.000'          1

  15             '2017-11-13 09:47:00.000'          2
  7              '2017-11-17 09:38:00.000'          2
  2              '2017-11-15 09:41:00.000'          2
  0              '2017-11-14 09:44:00.000'          2

  20             '2017-11-11 09:42:00.000'          3
  7              '2017-11-12 09:46:00.000'          3
  4              '2017-11-09 09:37:57.570'          3
  3              '2017-11-10 09:28:00.000'          3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said, it seems that you want something like this.

```
select
Score, ActivationTime, (rnk - 1) / 5 grp
from (
    select
        Score, ActivationTime, dense_rank()over(order by cast(ActivationTime as date) desc) rnk
from
    mytable
) t
order by grp, Score desc
```

You should give some sample data and the result you expect to get better help

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comments this is the way you would do it with N Days back.

First i create a dummy table with numbers on how many days i want to go back. This table i then loop over in my cursor to create my CTE statements. Last i union all my CTEs and then order them by activationtime and score

```
/*SCRIPT */

DECLARE @NDaysAgo nvarchar(2) = 20 --Change this based on how many days you want to go back
DECLARE @Number nvarchar(2)
DECLARE @sqlCreateNumbers nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AliasName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLUnion nvarchar(max)
 DECLARE @crlf nvarchar(max)
 SET @crlf = CHAR(13)
DECLARE @SQLTotal nvarchar(MAX)

Set @sqlCreateNumbers = '

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[numbers]'') AND type in (N''U''))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[numbers];

SELECT TOP '+@NDaysAgo+' IDENTITY(int,0,1) AS n 
into dbo.numbers
FROM MASTER..spt_values a, MASTER..spt_values b;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_1 ON numbers(n);


'
PRINT @sqlCreateNumbers

EXEC (@sqlCreateNumbers)


DECLARE SqlCur CURSOR FOR
Select DaysAgo = N,Alias = 'Today'+cast(N as nvarchar(50))
from dbo.Numbers
OPEN SqlCur
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCur
INTO @Number,@AliasName
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'with '+@AliasName+' as (
Select '''+@AliasName+''' as SourceName,Score,ActivationTime
from dbo.testactivation
Where cast(ActivationTime as date) = cast(dateadd(dd,'+@Number+',GETDATE()) as date)

)'

SET @SQLUnion = 'Select * from '+@AliasName+''

--PRINT @SQL
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCur INTO @Number,@AliasName
 END
 WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)

 BEGIN
 IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)

 SET @SQL = @SQL + ','+@AliasName+' as (
Select '''+@AliasName+''' as SourceName,Score,ActivationTime
from dbo.testactivation
Where cast(ActivationTime as date) = cast(dateadd(dd,-'+@Number+',GETDATE()) as date)

)'
SET @SQLUnion =  @SQLUnion + @crlf+ ' union all Select * from '+@AliasName+''
--PRINT @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCur INTO @Number,@AliasName
END

 CLOSE SqlCur
 DEALLOCATE SqlCur


SET @SQLTotal = @SQL + 'Select * from ( '+@SQLUnion+ ' ) x ORDER BY ACTIVATIONTIME DESC, SCORE DESC'

PRINT @SQLTotal --This will not show you all records since there is a limit to how much text it can show
Select @SQLTotal -- If you select it you can see the query

EXEC(@SQLTotal) --This will execute your statement, so you can see your descired result
```

**EDIT**
If you cannot use a variable you cant get NDays, then you have to hardcode it.

With one query

```
Select 'Data' as SourceName,Score,ActivationTime
from dbo.testactivation
Where cast(ActivationTime as date) between cast(dateadd(dd,0,GETDATE()) as date)
and cast(dateadd(dd,-20,GETDATE()) as date)
order by ActivationTime desc,score desc
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: I don't want do anything with SUM(score) but I want query on "Score" field. Also "Date of today" means Date of today like '2017-11-20 09:37:57.570' and it is not an alias name.

Comment: What? Why dont you just select your data then and order by score and activationtime?

Comment: It's working for part of data which have "ActivationTime" <= 3 days ago i think but how about N days ago.

Comment: @MiladRashidi Good, i have now made it dynmaic so you can choose N days ago

Comment: In my condition, it's not easy for me to get @NDaysAgo according to your response. Please help me in other way if possible. I should obtain result in exactly one query.

Comment: Then just use one CTE and group it by dates.

Comment: @SqlKindaGuy - Just like we tell the OPs, avoid display code as graphics.

Comment: @JeffModen Really? Its 5 years old.

Comment: @SqlKindaGuy - No... not really.  I posted that and the downvote to the wrong post and I apologize for the serious mistake.  If you do a minor edit to your answer above (just about anything will do from what I understand), it'll unfreeze my ability to vote on this post and I can undo the downvote.  Flag me with a comment when you're done and I'll fix the mistake. Again, I'm really sorry I made this mistake.